# Pass ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothList from android native code to java script code in react native

Tags: java, android, react-native, bluetooth

My app functionality has show bluetooth devices list on the app screen and on click of specific list item pair this specific bluetooth.
I implemented the bluetooth scan functionality in my app. In that I have facing problem one problem. The problem is, I defined the array list in my code,

```
List<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I added Bluetooth Device object in that list in the scanning process. I want to send this bluetoothList from native android code to java script code. So, please provide me solution how I send bluetoothList from native android code to java script code in react native?

Comment: You can't just ask to get a solution. Try to do it on your self.

Comment: @Louis Thanks for your response. I have tried one code for this. The code is given below,

Comment: if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                    WritableArray array = new WritableNativeArray();
                    try{                                                                                                                                                     
                        if(bluetoothList.size() != 0){
                        Gson gson = new Gson();

Comment: @Louis                        for(int i=0; i<bluetoothList.size(); i++){
                        BluetoothDevice bd = bluetoothList.get(i);
                        Toast.makeText(cntx, "Name: " +bd.getName() + "\tAddress: " +bd.getName() + "\tBondState: " +bd.getBondState() +  "\tgetType: " + bd.getType(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(bd));

Comment: @Louis                          Toast.makeText(cntx, "JSON Obj: " +jsonObject, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        WritableMap map = convertJsonToMap(jsonObject);
                        array.pushMap(map);
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(cntx, "List is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                    bluetoothNames = new String[bluetoothNameList.size()];
                    bluetoothNames = bluetoothNameList.toArray(bluetoothNames);
                WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();

Comment: @Louis                    WritableArray promiseArray = Arguments.createArray();
                    for(int i=0;i<bluetoothNames.length;i++){
                        promiseArray.pushString(bluetoothNames[i]);
                    }
                    params.putArray("bluetoothArray", array);
                    params.putArray("bluetoothNameArray", promiseArray);
                    sendEvent(cntx, "BluetoothDataEvent", params);

Comment: @Louis                     Toast.makeText(cntx, "Bluetooth scan is finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(cntx, "JSON Exception Occured ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }

Comment: @Louis  But, I have face problem with this code. The problem is I have receiving map is empty at javascript side. I think the issue at conversion of object in json. Object not converting into json. So, please help me for solving this problem.

Comment: I would suggest moving the code from comments into a properly formatted section of your question in order to get help with this.